# How to take a string parameter (will be the path name of a file) and perform File methods like exists() and setReadOnly on it?

Tags: java, string, file-io

```
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.FileSystems; 
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    public class Attrib {
/* Command::
attrib name       where name must be the name of a file and its path.
Action:
Makes the file read only.

 */
public Attrib(String name){
   final Path path = Paths.get(name);
   Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:readonly", true); 
   throws NoSuchFileException;



}

private void f(String name){
    System.out.print(name);
}
```

}
The purpose of this program is make an existing file read only.
For some reason, I keep getting the error code  when I try to compile "cannot find symbol - method exists()".  I guess you cannot perform exists(), or any other File method on a path-name that is represented as a string?  Maybe I can convert the string path-name to a file object or something?

Answer (score 0):

Use java.nio.file, it has much better support for file attributes.

Supposing you run on Windows, for instance, this code will work:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(thename);

Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:readonly", true);
```

You can catch the exception thrown by `Files.setAttribute()` which can, for instance, throw `NoSuchFileException` if the file does not exist etc.

An equivalent of the code above can be:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(thename);

final DosFileAttributeView view 
    = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, DosFileAttributeView.class);

view.setReadOnly(true);
```

In fact, it is recommended to go through a `FileAttributeView` if you wish to change more than one parameter.

Note however that this code is of course "non portable" in the sense that it will only work for `FileSystem`s which support the `dos` file attributes. On Unix systems for instance you might want to change the POSIX permissions instead.

Comment: hey thank you for the response.  I have been messing around with my code trying to get it to work.  I imported java.nio.file.Files, FileSystems, and Path and now i am getting an error here: final Path path = Paths.get(name);    it says "cannot find symbol - variable Paths".  Any idea what went wrong? My updated code is above

Comment: Don't you use Java 7+?

Comment: That's not what I am asking. And note that you didn't seem to have imported java.nio.file.Paths, which you also need. Also, I don't use BlueJ, so I can't help with this IDE.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by java 7+ then.  After importing Paths, there is a  error code regarding my throws clause, but I do not have time now to figure out where it should be declared because I have to go to work now.  I'll do some research on it later tonight.  I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but just know I tried giving you a plus one. Thanks again @fge